# How to install PIL in system library using homebrew?

Tags: python-imaging-library, homebrew

In a new SnowLeopard install, I'd like to use homebrew to install PIL. However the recipe installs PIL under cellar instead of in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages. Is there a way to change the install directory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since there seems to be no "accepted" way of installing homebrew eggs into the system site-packages, here is what I ended up doing:

```
% brew install pil
% easy_install pip
% pip install pil
```

The homebrew install grabs and installs all of PIL's dependencies (especially jpeg). The later easy_install then uses them when compiling PIL for the system site-packages. Freetype support doesn't show up in the "easy-installed" version, but that's fine for my purposes.

As my initial goal was to provide a simple way for a web designer to build a django development environment, having an unused homebrew PIL installed is not really a problem.

Hope this helps someone. Still hoping there's a better answer out there.

Answer (score 34):

Instead of installing pip and another PIL, you can just make a symlink

```
brew install pil
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/pil/1.1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL
```

Tested on Lion, on Snow Leopard, you may need to change paths to use /python2.6 /Python/2.6.

Comment: This is the best solution IMO. It's clean and simple. Homebrew installs its stuff in /usr/local/bin and trying to wrangle it out of there is really catastrophic (and a real pain). Better to symlink the PIL package to where most things OS X looks for it (under /Library/Python/{version} than bust up homebrew for one simple egg.

Comment: I followed your steps but still couldn't import PIL

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Mountain Lion. `import Image` still fails after creating the symlink. Aren't we supposed to add the path to a `.pth` file somewhere?

Comment: @yorch Yes, it had been working from the start. The proper import is `from PIL import Image`, not `import Image`.

Comment: On 10.8 I already had a `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL` so `ln` failed silently. I had to move it away `sudo mv /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL{,-original}` and run `ln` again, now it works fine ! =D Thank @Frank !

Answer (score 16):

It seems that Pillow replaced PIL in homebrew. The new command is:

```
brew install Homebrew/python/pillow
```

Answer (score 1):

As @BarnabasSzabolcs mentioned, newer versions named pillow.
an alternative to `brew install Homebrew/python/pillow` is `pip install pillow`. You may need to add `sudo`, depends on your python environment permissions.

p.s.
that answer could be fit better as a comment, 14 credits to go...