# Can't locate setup.py file to install PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am following the instructions on the following page, and I am not sure which setup.py file it is referring to where I need to change `JPEG_ROOT = libinclude(“/usr/local”)` (I am a beginner). Mac OS X, Python 2.7.

Here is the [link](http://appelfreelance.com/2010/06/libjpeg-pil-snow-leopard-python2-6-_jpeg_resync_to_restart/), and below is an abstract:

> Next get PIL and untar it
>
> http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz tar -zxvf
>   Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz cd Imaging-1.1.6
>
> If you already have PIL I would recommend running
>
> sudo rm -Rf build
>
> to clean any existing builds, this has caused me loads of errors and
>   gray hairs!
>
> in your setup.py file run find JPEG_ROOT
>
> amend it so it looks as follows
>
> JPEG_ROOT = libinclude(“/usr/local”)
>
> Next move onto the build
>
> sudo python setup.py build

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: To make future maintenance easier, install Python via Homebrew and follow the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546860/how-to-install-pil-in-system-library-using-homebrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you untar the archive, at the root of Imaging-1.1.6, is setup.py.

Answer (score 0):

It's referring to the `setup.py` in the root of the extracted files.

Comment: I change into the PIL directory, but there is no setup.py file there. Am I not looking in the correct place?

Comment: The "PIL" directory? I'm not talking about the root of the archive itself.